# M503 command is reporting "Maximum feedrates" with duplicate and empty values: M203 X200.00 Y200.00 Z5.00 E Y1000.00 Z100.00 E5000.00

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, g-code, octoprint, skr-mini-e3

I'm pretty stumped on this one.

Investigating an issue I was having with an OctoPrint plugin, I've come to realize my `M503` command is reporting duplicate and empty values. This is not an issue with the plugin, but an issue with the native `M503` output.

**Here's what I'm getting:**

```
echo:  G21    ; Units in mm (mm)
echo:  M149 C ; Units in Celsius

echo:; Filament settings: Disabled
echo:  M200 S0 D1.75

echo:; Steps per unit:
echo: M92 X80.00 Y80.00 Z400.00 E93.00

echo:; Maximum feedrates (units/s):
echo:  M203 X200.00 Y200.00 Z5.00 E Y1000.00 Z100.00 E5000.00

echo:; Acceleration (units/s2): P<print_accel> R<retract_accel> T<travel_accel>
echo:  M204 P500.00 R500.00 T500.00

echo:; Advanced: B<min_segment_time_us> S<min_feedrate> T<min_travel_feedrate> J<junc_dev>
echo:  M205 B20000.00 S0.00 T0.00 J0.08

echo:; Home offset:
echo:  M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00

echo:; Material heatup parameters:
echo:  M145 S0 H185.00 B45.00 F255
echo:  M145 S1 H240.00 B110.00 F255

echo:; PID settings:
echo:  M301 P21.73 I1.54 D76.55

; Controller Fan
echo:  M710 S255 I0 A1 D60 ; (100% 0%)

echo:; Stepper driver current:
echo:  M906 X580 Y580 Z580
echo:  M906 T0 E650

echo:; Driver stepping mode:
echo:  M569 S1 X Y Z
echo:  M569 S1 T0 E

echo:; Linear Advance:
echo:  M900 K0.00

echo:; Filament load/unload lengths:
echo:  M603 L350.00 U400.00
```

**This is the problem:**

```
echo:; Maximum feedrates (units/s):
echo:  M203 X200.00 Y200.00 Z5.00 E Y1000.00 Z100.00 E5000.00
```

Why would my feedrate be reporting an empty "E", an additional "E5000" and then *two of each* "X" and "Z" arguments as well? At first, I thought maybe it was a duplicate Z-Y-Z-E followed by another.. but it's followed by Y-Z-E only.

**My printer specs:**

- Ender-3 Pro
- SKR Mini 2.0
- Micro Swiss hot end
- Direct drive extruder
- Marlin build is straight from the [BigTreeTech repo](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/firmware/V2.0/Marlin-2.0.8.2.x-SKR-mini-E3-V2.0)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you get the same if you just send M203? Also to be clear this is not causing a issue directly that you know of correct?